# Getting phone type information form Telephony Manager

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I want to know how do I access the phone type info [whether it is GSM or CDMA] from `TelephonyManager`. which function can I use for this:

My code for this is :

```
SubscriptionManager sm = SubscriptionManager.from(context);

List<SubscriptionInfo> sil = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
sim_value[0]= sil.get(0).getDisplayName().toString();
sim_value[1]= sil.get(0).getIccId().toString();
sim_value[2]= String.valueOf(sil.get(0).getSimSlotIndex());
sim_value[3]= sil.get(0).getCarrierName().toString();
```

Comment: try code which i have posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using Telephony Manager

**you must declare following permission in AndroidManifest file..**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Have an  object of TelephonyMnager

```
TelephonyManager  tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Get the Phone Type CDMA/GSM/NONE

```
  int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType();

        switch (phoneType)
        {
                case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
                           // your code
                               break;
                case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) 
                           // your code                 
                               break;
                case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
                           // your code              
                                break;
         }
```

For more refer this [Telephony Manager](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/getting-imei-number-and-other-details.html)

Comment: Yess. It worked and i upvote your answer ..but actually i want to use SubscriptionManager instead of TelephonyManager . If you have any info regarding this then let me know. @Vishal Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (tm.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { 
    // device is 3G CDMA           
}
else if (tm.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) { 
   // device is 2G GSM         
}
```