# How to get the Radio type of Android phone(GSM,CDMA,WCDMA,LTE)

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am using the google maps geolocation API. There is a field in there named radioType and the only supported values are GSM,CDMA,WCDMA, and LTE. Although these field is optional, I included it for more accurate results. I tried searching for code to find this. But I haven't found any. I want to find the radio type of the android phone. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be it is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072912/getting-phone-type-information-form-telephony-manager

Answer (score 3):

You can use telephonyManager to get the current network type

final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

and use the following function to get the network type

telephony.getNetworkType();