# Is the value of an Android phone's radio type always GSM, LTE, CDMA or WCDMA?

Tags: java, android, google-api, telephonymanager

I'm creating an app that uses Google's Geolocation API, as documented
[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).

As part of the POST request I need to send to their API, I need to include **The mobile radio type**, `radioType`. The question of how to receive that has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469700/how-to-get-the-radio-type-of-android-phonegsm-cdma-wcdma-lte).

My question is as follows:

The `telephoneManager.getNetworkType()` function that I'm apparently supposed to use returns one of 18 values, documented as constants [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

Does that mean that the `radioType` as described by Google's geolocation API really can be 18 different values? So if it turns out that my radio type is not one of the four they support (GSM, LTE, CDMA or WCDMA), I'm simply out of luck and will have to suffer the loss of accuracy from not including `radioType` in my request?

I have a feeling that I'm mixing up the terms `radio type` and `network type` somehow, the documentation is a bit confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your phone can have 4 different radio types, GSM, CDMA, WCDMA, and LTE. But each radio type can have different network types.

The 2G radio (GSM/CDMA) can have the following network types:

- GPRS
- EDGE
- CDMA
- 1xRTT
- IDEN

The 3G radios (WCDMA) can have:

- UMTS
- EVD0_0
- EVD0_A
- HSDPA
- HSUPA
- HSPA
- EVDO_B
- EHRPD
- HSPAP

The 4G radio (LTE) can have:

- LTE

So yes, you have to send the radio type and **not** the network type, which means there are only 4 possible values as shown in the Google API docs.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341777/2544098) for mapping the network type to a radio type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. 

Just a quick follow-up: There are 18 documented network types, and you only listed 14. The missing ones are GSM, 1xRTT, IDEN, and IWLAN. Gsm is obvious, but where do the rest belong? From your link I can discern that iDen and 1xRTT are both 2g, i.e. either CDMA or GSM, but I still need to know which.

In general, you group GSM and CDMA network types together. In your provided link, they're all bunched together and called "2G". However, I need to differentiate them for the purposes of the API. Which goes where?

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you only listed 13, since you listed EHRPD twice. If that means both 3G and 4G can be EHRPD, what radio type should I choose in that case? TD_SCDMA is the last missing network type. I'm sorry if these are stupid questions, but I don't have a solid grasp of what there terms mean yet! I just want to be able to correctly map them to one of the four primary radio types.

Comment: @finnss it looks like TD-SCDMA is an alternative to W-CDMA in China